# Is there any reference such as MailKit to add in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, email, visual-web-part

I am developing a visual webpart in SharePoint 2010 project and I have to deal with emails in my visual part.

I tried to add MailKit reference to my project and it keeps telling me that it work only with .Net 4.0 target framework and SharePoint 2010 has 3.5 framework.

Is there any other reference to use and how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the built in sharepoint utility:

```
SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, false, false, "ss@test.com", "subject", "body");
```

[SPUtility.SendEmail Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: not for sending mails but for List all my emails